# Parts of model are occluded strangely in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, render, zbuffer

I'm rendering a barrel object in Android with GLES20. The barrel is not rendered correctly and it's not clear to me where the problem is (texture? model? culling? depth?):

[image]
[image]

I've tried debugging with Google's debugger. The model can be rendered correctly in the debugger and the texture is also loaded correctly.

[image]

I have tried various parameters related to `glFrontFace`, `glBlendFunc`, `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and `GL_CULL_FACE`. But so far none of the combinations can render the barrel successfully.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this rendering?

PS: In the debugger GAPID, the depth buffer seem to be all black (Y=1.0). But I'm not sure if this is a issue with the debugger? I have enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` with `GL_LEQUAL`. I've also used `setEGLConfigChooser(true)`.

Comment: Do you request context with a depth buffer? Do you clear the depth buffer? How do you make your projection matrix?

Comment: What did you pass to `setEGLConfigChooser`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes and yes. The proj mat is calculated with gyro data and seems to work on simple models like a cube.

Comment: @BDL true: needDepth

Comment: @TimGuo Camera rotation is view matrix. But what about projection?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `Matrix.perspectiveM(matrix, 0, 56, (float) width / (float) height, 0, 5);`

Comment: I assume 0 and 5 are near and far planes? Near plane can't be 0, it has to be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @HolyBlackCat!

Both `zNear` and `zFar` need to be positive. The messed up perspective matrix produces this weired looking rendering.